# Last Morse call for Thomas?

Tags: cw, q-codes

What does this mean:

> CQ de KYHP QTC? K

My father-in-law was a radio operator in the merchant marines during WWII — this was his last writing.

Answer (score 5):

That was a Morse code message, using common abbreviations to save time. Here it is translated into plain language:

> [CQ=] Calling any station, [de=] from radio station KYHP.  [QTC?=] How many telegrams have you to send? [K=] Go ahead, I'm listening.

The first letter K means that the station was a US station; however, it may or may not have actually been located there.

The call sign KYHP has apparently been reassigned to a commercial TV station.